# Is there some sort of bug in jQueryUI datepicker in IE9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

```
   <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtdate").datepicker(); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Works fine in FF, but on IE9 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 the datepicker shows but I'm not able to select and put a date in the input-textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this too.  The problem is a result of IE Enhanced Security Configuration.  You can turn it off by following these directions:
http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-in-windows-server-2008/

Just keep in mind that you are taking a calculated risk by turning it off.